# SIebel Data Mapping issue

Tags: mapping, siebel

We have a web service that integrated our siebel system which another system.
Any update in the account would trigger the web service. But webservice trigger is not happening due to the following error:

```
Error invoking service 'EAI Data Transformation Engine', method 'Execute' at step 'Generate Org Msg'.(SBL-BPR-00162)
--
Error parsing expression 'Name='Master's College & University', Type='LN_INDUSTR
```

I believe it is because of the apostrophe in the Name = 'Master's College & University'.

There is this mapping which is responsible for mapping our value to the external service:

```
Source Expression:  IfNull([&IndustryClass],[LN Industry Class])
```

I tried using the InStr function to see if that solves the issue, but to no avail
    InStr([LN Industry Class],[LN Industry Class])

Do we have a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Could you post the source XML for this ? InStr function does a substring search, so above usage is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the single quote (apostrophe: `'`) with a double quote (`"`) and wrap the text with single quotes.

More info [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/siebel-answers/siebel-escript-avoiding-query-could-not-be-run-because-there-is-an-invalid-character-sbldat60236-and-sbldat00403-34371).